# Uploading a c# application to a facebook application

Tags: c#, facebook

I have created a Windows application using C# and would like to know how to upload it to Facebook application.

I have set up the Facebook application, all I need to do is add the application. I can't seem to find out how.

Comment: You can't load an arbitrary program as a Facebook app. Perhaps I've misunderstood, though; please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have an already completed application which works normally as a windows application. There is no way I can convert this to a facebook app?

Comment: No, you can't do that. Facebook applications are web applications.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook applications are not true applications in the sense of the word.  You do not download or install Facebook apps... they are more like web applications that you log in to with your Facebook account.  When you "add" a Facebook application to your Facebook account, all you are really doing is setting some permission flags to give that application access to your Facebook data.  Once you've "added" it, each time you load a page from the app, Facebook sends it your Facebook id, which lets the app interact with you and work with your social data.  There's no concept of downloading involved.

If your C# app is a desktop application, then you can still integrate it with Facebook, but you're going to need to do a bit more work.  You'll need Facebook Connect in order to establish the proper communication.  You might want to start with [Authorizing and Authentication for Desktop Applications](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Authorization_and_Authentication_for_Desktop_Applications), and do a bit of poking around in that wiki to find out more.